# Electron - prevent window close but allow redirects

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a simple Electron app. The main process would open up a browser window (I call it `mainWindow`) and I would like to prevent users from closing it (for kiosk purposes; FYI, I already have `kiosk: true`. I'm just trying to add another layer of protection).

I have set up a `beforeunload` event listener in my renderer process like shown below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
   console.log('I do not want to be closed')
   e.returnValue = false 
}
```

This works well. It prevents closing of the window in every way (at least in macOS) and I could quit the process with `mainWindow.destroy()` in the main process. However, by doing this, I am not able to redirect my window to any other HTML files, no matter with `location.href` or `mainWindow.loadFile()` because it would fire the `beforeunload` event and prevent it from redirecting.

One solution I could think of is to use a fullscreen `iframe` in `mainWindow` and do the redirections there, but the communication between sandboxed `iframe` and the window that uses `ipcRenderer` would be too complex.

Apart from that, is there a work around to distinguish whether a `beforeunload` event was fired for it being closed or just being redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the DOM `onbeforeunload` handler, you could listen for the `BrowserWindow`'s very own `close` event in the Main Process, which is emitted *before* `onbeforeunload` but only when the window is actually going to close.

As per the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-close), you would have to call `e.preventDefault ()` to prevent closing, but you wouldn't have to worry about page redirects.

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require ("electron");

let window;
// However you're initialising your BrowserWindow...

window.on ("close", event => {
    event.preventDefault ();
});
```

The [documentation for `#destroy ()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#windestroy) states that it will not emit the `"close"` event, thus everything should work as before, except you're listening for the event on the Main Process and gain window reloading.